# Ability to grant moksha

Tags: gods, moksha, goddess

There is always the question of “Who I Supreme-Lord Shiva,Lord Vishnu,or Devi (Parvati)?”

**My question is:Are each of these 3 deities equally capable to give their devotees moksha?Or does this depend  on the sect?**

Especially in light of deities like Lord Ganesha,Lord Kartikeya,Mother Lakshmi,etc.,as these deities are also worshipped,but in a purpose centric way(mostly):like to eliminate obstacles,grant victory /strength,and to be wealthy (respectively).Or do they also grant moksha the same way as say Lord Vishnu?

Edit:

I am not asking “Who Gives Moksha”.I know that Lord Shiva,Vishnu and Mother Parvati/Devican do so.

My question is ,**are other deities just as capable to give mukti?**

Edit 2:

I read the “Arogyam ...” answer,and it directly states “Lord Vishnu” for moksha.But neither of the suggestions talk about the capability of **other deities **.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126187/discussion-on-question-by-amethyst-ability-to-grant-moksha).